# Rational numbers $t$ for which $3t^3+10t^2-3t$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory

That is the question : Find the rational numbers $t$ for which $$3t^3+10t^2-3t$$  is an integer $?$

Now $0$ is an obvious choice . But how do we find out the non zero solutions ? What is the process ?

Comment: Well, any integer is an obvious choice too, no?

Comment: To reduce by $t$ why not?

Comment: @Soke : Yes it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $t=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}$, relatively prime to each other.

$$\begin{align}
3t^3+10t^2-3t&\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\iff \frac{3p^3+10p^2q-3pq^2}{q^3}&\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}$$

Since $q$ divides the latter two terms in the numerator, $q$ must divide $3$. Of course if $q=1$, then $t$ is an integer, and so will be $3t^3+10t^2-3t$. So we focus on $q=3$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{3p^3+30p^2-27p}{27}&\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\iff\frac{3p^3+30p^2}{27}&\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\iff\frac{p^2(p+10)}{9}&\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{align}$$

This last statement is true if and only if $9$ divides $p+1$ (since $9$ is relatively prime to $p$).

So the set of $t$ you are looking for are the integers, together with rational numbers of the form $\frac{9k-1}{3}$.